# I am facing issues while starting mysql on macOS

Tags: mysql, macos

Whenever I install mysql on macOS I get this error while starting it

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

I have tried the password which I got during the installation. The error then is :

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

I have also tried using root as a password or completely letting it blank but none of this worked

NOTE: I am using mysql using the MAMP setup and it is running just fine there.
It is located at:

*/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql*

I am able to run as root from there. Is it due to I am trying to run as root from two places? Please help me out.

Comment: what's the actual command you used? can you login as a guest (just type mysql)?

Comment: I used mysql -u root -proot as root is my password. No I am not able to login as a guest. It gives the same error everytime